# Using a 3D Lookup Table from a 2D PNG in GLSL and OpenGL in C++

Tags: opengl, colors, glsl, shader, lookup-tables

I'm trying to load a PNG representing a color look up table, for my color grading shader.

Here is the Neutral LUT png representation:

[image: img]

I'm unsure how to properly load this as a 3d texture and then pass it into my shader. Clearly, there is color transformation occurring, **but I end up with a noisy rainbow mess, rather than the neutral image.** For example: 
 [image: img]

Here is how I create the texture

```
    glGenTextures(1, &lut_texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, lut_texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGB8, 32, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGB,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &lut_image[0]);
```

Here is how I pass it into the shader:

```
    glUseProgram(colorGradingProgram);
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(colorGradingProgram, "tex0"), 0);
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(colorGradingProgram, "lut"), 1);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffers[0]); 
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, lut_texture); 
    drawQuad();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0); 
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); 
    glUseProgram(0);
```

Here is the frag shader (using GLSL 1.x):

```
uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler3D lut;

void main(void)
{
  vec4 colorIn = texture2D(tex0, gl_TexCoord[0].st);

  vec4 colorOut;    
  colorOut.rgb = texture3D(lut, colorIn.rgb).rgb;   

  gl_FragColor = colorOut;  
}
```

What I'm most unclear about is dimensions specified for the call to

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGB8, 32, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGB,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &lut_image[0]);
```

Depending on what values I use here, my results vary wildly. The closest thing I can get to a neutral image, is using (2,2,2) as width,height,depth, but this does not resonate with me intuitively and is not totally neutral. I do not understand what I am doing wrong or how this is supposed to be achieved (translating the 2d texture to a 3d volume)

Comment: One problem is that you have blue and green channels swapped (due to the mismatch of the memory layouts between your file and what `glTexImage3D` expects). But this is not the whole story. **How do you load `lut_image` into memory?** Also seeing the image without the color correction may be helpful.

Comment: Most lilkly cause for the rainbowy colors is that you load `lut_image` as 32-bit RGBA. Try passing `GL_RGBA` in the third to last parameter to `glTexImage3D`.

Comment: @ybungalobill can you tell me how you can tell the green and blue channels are swapped? I'm not seeing the mismatch in the code but I did notice this and correct it in my shader

Comment: The first row in your PNG contains the G=0 plane for all RB value. Your `glTexImage3D` will load into the first plane of your 3d texture, which is B=0 and indexed by RG in [0,1]. Therefore it is swapped. Correcting it in the shader is indeed an option, but I would rather use the technique I describe below to load the texture in the correct layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my educated guess from the comments above, you need to

1. Upload each texture layer separately.
2. Specify `GL_RGBA` format.

The folowing code should do that (disclaimer -- untested):

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGB8, 32, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 1024);
for(int z = 0; z < 32; ++z) {
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 32*z);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 0, 0, z, 32, 32, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &lut_image[0]);
}
```

Comment: Using RGBA fixed this for me.